# Determine if there exists a $\frac{2\pi}{w}$ periodic solution and find it if so

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given $\vec{\dot{x}}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\\cos(wt)\end{pmatrix}$ and $w\neq\pm1\in\mathbb{R}$
> (i) Solve the initial value $\vec{x(0)}=\vec{x_0}$ and find the solution of the initial value problem
> (ii) Determine if there exists a $\frac{2\pi}{w}$ periodic solution and find it if so

I've found that the the homog. solution is $\vec{x_H}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\-\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}y_{01}+\begin{pmatrix}\sin(t)\\\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}y_{02}$
and the particular is $\vec{x_P}=\frac{-1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\cos(t(1+w))}{1+w}+\frac{\cos(t(1-w))}{1-w}+E\\\frac{\sin(t(1+w))}{1+w}+\frac{\sin(t(1-w))}{1-w}+F\end{pmatrix}$ so the solution is $\vec{x}=\vec{x_H}+\vec{x_P}$ to the IVP

For the second part I'm not sure how to approach any hint?

Comment: You got homog. solution and particular solution - a general solution is $A\vec{Xh}+B\vec{Xp}$. Now you have to try to find constants A and B to get a solution with the period $\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav the constants wont change the solution no?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - You have only one arbitrary constant, of course. General solution is $A\vec{xh}+\vec{Xp}$

Comment: I ment that even multiply by A we won't change the period so I can check on the 3 periodic functions no?

Comment: I suppose that in one dimension we won't. But your $x$ is two-dimensional: $x(t)=\binom{x1(t)}{x2(t)}$. I may suppose that you have to find such $A$ that $\binom{x1(t1)}{x2(t1)}=\binom{x1(t1+\frac{2\pi}{\omega})}{x1(t2+\frac{2\pi}{\omega})}$. Does it make sense?